# Apache Oozie trying to give spark jar precedence through shell action but the workflow just hangs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, oozie

I am getting a jar conflict for the *POI Java Library* between my spark submit using *Poi 3.17* and rapid miner jar on the hadoop class path using *POI 3.14*

So I am trying to give my jar precedence through a shell action.

I read that this is possible through java action but I would prefer to use a shell action instead.

Attached is my oozie workflow using these 2 properties below but when I add these additional properties my workflow just hangs

```
<property>
          <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.classpath.user.precedence</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
```

**Attached is the full workflow**

```
 <workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='Stuff' xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.2">
  <global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
        <value>${queueName}</value>
      </property>

        <property>
          <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.classpath.user.precedence</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>


    </configuration>
  </global>

  <credentials>
    <credential name="hive2_credentials" type="hive2">
      <property>
        <name>hive2.jdbc.url</name>
        <value>jdbc:hive2://${hive2_server}:${hive2_port}/default;ssl=true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hive2.server.principal</name>
        <value>hive/${hive2_server}@${kerberos_realm}</value>
      </property>
    </credential>
  </credentials>



<start to="spark2-submit"/>

  <!-- Spark job to process the Vistalink Consumer - Shell-action -->
  <action name="spark2-submit">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">


      <exec>spark_submit.sh</exec> 
      <argument>dev_submit.config</argument>
      <argument>2018-08-08</argument>



      <env-var>HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf</env-var>
      <env-var>kerberos_realm=${kerberos_realm}</env-var>
      <env-var>edgeUser=${edgeUser} </env-var>
      <env-var>queueName=${queueName}</env-var>
      <file>${keyTabLocation}/${keyTabName}</file>


      <file>${nameNode}/abc.sh#abc.sh</file>

    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="end"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="fail">
   <message>"WF: failed"</message>
  </kill>
     <end name='end'/>
    </workflow-app>
```

I tried as well adding the configuration parameter within my shell action but the workflow just hangs doesnt event start .

I tried editing the classpath by modifying

```
export CLASSPATH=`echo $OLDCLASSPATH | sed 's|:/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/lib/radoop/rapidminer_libs-7.6.1.jar||g' | sed 's|:/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/lib/radoop/radoop_hive-v4.jar||g'`

export AUX_CLASSPATH=`echo $AUX_CLASSPATH | sed 's|/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/lib/radoop/rapidminer_libs-7.6.1.jar:||g' | sed 's|/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/lib/radoop/radoop_hive-v4.jar||g'`

export MR2_CLASSPATH=`echo $MR2_CLASSPATH | sed 's|/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/lib/radoop/rapidminer_libs-7.6.1.jar:||g' | sed 's|/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/lib/radoop/radoop_hive-v4.jar||g'`


export SCM_DEFINES_SCRIPTS=`echo $SCM_DEFINES_SCRIPTS | sed 's|:/opt/cloudera/parcels/RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1/meta/parcel_env.sh||g'`

export PARCEL_DIRNAMES=`echo $PARCEL_DIRNAMES | sed 's|RAPIDMINER_LIBS-7.6.1||g'`
```

After this I did check the java classpath and there was no rapid miner 
by referencing java.class.path

Using Apache Spark 2.3 and CDH 5.14

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, can't you control the classspath in script `spark-sbumit.sh`? And why not using https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html ?

Comment: I tried to control the classpath in the `spark-submit.sh` using different spark configs it did not work . The jars are being injected by the yarn container.  Ill take a look at the spark action extensions. Thanks

Comment: Did you check that these properties are not deprecated? I personally would bet on `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first`

Comment: But anyway that would work only for a Java / Spark / Sqoop action, i.e. a job bootstrapped from a JAR. A Linux shell does not care about "launcher" Java properties! There is also the Spark property `spark.yarn.user.classpath.first` but it applies only to executors, not to the driver itself _(unless you start the session in `yarn-cluster` mode)_

Comment: Thanks for you help I tried using `spark.yarn.user.classpath.first ` unfortunately that does not seem to work correctly on my cluster . I did not yet have time to convert my code to  java or spark action but will try that soon.